# C# Decompiled source errors

Tags: c#

I decompiled a C# Executable a friend gave me. When i tried running it in dnspy these kind of errors came up.
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration main.g.cs   966
Error   CS1003  Syntax error, '>' expected  main.g.cs   969

Code is:

```
    public static readonly global::SynapseMainUI.Class8 <>9;

    // Token: 0x0400006A RID: 106
    public static global::System.Func<string, bool> <>9__33_1;
```

Comment: Yes, decompiled IL is generally not valid C#. Decompilers care about making the binary readable, not making sure you can compile it again. What's your question, if any?

Comment: My question is how would i fix this?

Comment: It depends on *why* you want to recompile the decompiled binary (as opposed to, you know, keeping it as a binary, or getting the actual source from your, um, friend). Even so, any answer is probably going to devolve into "get a different decompiler", and recommendations for particular tools are off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are seeing are part of the [sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that the C# compiler uses.

The compiler won't let you use the prefix `<>` in code, not because it is invalid, but because it is reserved for compiler things, like hoisting lambdas, or other `sugary` things.

If you want to learn more about the compiler, and why it does things like this, watch [this pluralsight course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/csharp-language-internals)

Comment: I see that, but how would i fix this?

Comment: You don't. That is a much too difficult task to do manually, and if it was easy to do, the talented guys and gals at Jetbrains would've done it in dotPeek